# Using R, how to reference variable variables (or variables variable) a la PHP

Tags: php, r, variables, variable-assignment, variable-variables

Using R stats, I want to access a variable variable scenario similar to PHP double-dollar-sign technique:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

**Specifically, I am looking for a function in R that is equivalent to $$ in PHP.**

---

***UPDATE:  The approved answer contains the basic function needed***

```
##################################
    hello="hello world";
    a="hello";
    result=get(a);
    print(result);
##################################
```

---

In PHP, I can assign `$a="hello";` and `$hello="hello world";`. I can then use an `eval` to dynamic change variables; this is called a variables variable in php, using two dollar signs ($$): `echo($$a);` will print "hello world". It evaluate $a which is hello, then evaluates $hello.

So, I have a regression setup using R, with 4 data options and 3 model options.  I perform about 60 lines of stats using R and mainly the library plm, but also tseries, lmtest (a bunch of diagnostic tests, a pooled OLS, fixed effects (FE), and random effects (RE) with tests for heteroskedasticity, serial autocorrelation, cross-dependence autocorrelation, and so on.  If these elements exist, I smartly update the standard errors depending on what is present:  only hetero [vcovHC white], hetero-serial or hetero-cross [vcovHC arellano], all [vcovSCC Driscoll-Kraay].

In the end, I want to display the adjusted regression models FE/RE for 3 model options on a page.  Each page will have one of the four data options.  I want to output this in Latex.  So in this scenario, I need a variables variable approach.  I am trying `eval(`, `parse(`, `substitute(`, `assign(`.

so consider I have a variable in R `mDat.total` that contains the data I need for a regression.  I also have `mDat.hi`, `mDat.mid`, `mDat.low`.  These 4 elements, I can represent as a list of strings pointing to the variable:

`d = c("mDat.total","mDat.low","mDat.mid","mDat.hi");  # data loop`

Similarly, for the models, I have formula datatypes (using formula,Formula,pForumla such as `model.main = emp~wage+capital|lag(wage,1)+capital`:

`m = c("model.main","model.lone","model.interaction"); # model loop`

I want to loop over i in d, j in m, and perform a bunch of regressions.

```
for(i in 1:length(d))
    {
    myData = $$d[i];
    for j in 1:length(m))
        {
        myModel = $$m[j];
        ... ### do stuff with myData, myModel
            that has been assigned the values of myData (a data frame) 
            and myModel (a model specification)
```

For `i=1;j=1`, myData evaluates to be the `mDat.total` dataframe, and myModel evaluates to be the `model.main`

**Ideally, I want a standalone function using R that behaves like $$ (e.g., in above pseudo code, replace $$ with a function doubleEvaluate(x) or VariableVariable(x).**

Thanks in advance.

monte

{x:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [get()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/get) to obtain environment variables from string values. Additionally, consider the nested `lapply()` between dataframe and model lists for more organized returned object. Nested `for` loops would require appending each iteration into growing list unless you just need to output. Below examples use linear models, `lm()`:

```
model1 <- y ~ x1
model2 <- y ~ x2
model3 <- y ~ x3

dflist <- c("df1","df2","df3")
modelist <- c("model1", "model2", "model3")

# MODEL DATA RETURNS NESTED LIST OF 3 ELEMENTS 
# EACH WITH CORRESPONDING DATA METRICS (COEFF, RESIDUALS, ETC.)
modeldata <- lapply(dflist,
                    function(x) {                  
                    df<-get(x)       
                    lapply(modelist,
                           function(y) {
                           model <- get(y)
                           ols <- lm(model, df)                                          
                    })                  
               })

# BELOW CREATES MODEL SUMMARY LIST OF 3 ELEMENTS 
# FOR FIRST THREE MODELS USING FIRST DATASET
modelsummary <- lapply(modeldata[[1]], summary)
```

Example with nested `for` loop:

```
# INITIALIZE A LIST TO CONTAIN DATA
modeldata <- list()

for (i in dflist){  
  df<-get(i)
  for (j in modelist){    
    model <- get(j)

    # APPEND TO MODELDATA LIST
    # FINAL RETURN IS LARGE LIST OF ALL DATA MODELS
    modeldata <- c(modeldata, lm(model, df))    
  }  
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Yes, I concur that lapply is a correct approach, but there are times the logic of lapply doesn't make as much sense as a procedural for-loop.  But, you are probably right about the growing list.  Let me code this and see if it works.  I am almost positive I can get this to work, but for any variable type, is there a $$ approach that can work with R?

Comment: So in your scenario, you are building only one object (e.g. ols).  I need to perform several calls, and store in a master list... I tried replacing your line  <code>ols <- lm(model, df)</code> with a bunch of calls, and finish with a list statement <code>list(unittest.1=unittest.1, unittest.2=unittest.2, bptest=bptest, viftest=viftest, pdwtest=pdwtest, pbgtest=pbgtest, pooled.reg=pooled.reg, pooled.sum=pooled.sum, pooled.xsd=pooled.xsd, pooled.coef=pooled.coef, fixed.reg=fixed.reg, ..., random.reg=random.reg, ..., hausmantest=hausmantest);</code>

Comment: In the list scenario above, it returns an object of the correct dimensionality, but all values are FALSE.

Comment: > str(modeldata)
List of 4
$ :List of 3
 ..$ : logi FALSE
 ..$ : logi FALSE
 ..$ : logi FALSE
$ :List of 3
 ..$ : logi FALSE
 ..$ : logi FALSE
 ..$ : logi FALSE
$ :List of 3
 ..$ : logi FALSE
 ..$ : logi FALSE
 ..$ : logi FALSE
$ :List of 3
 ..$ : logi FALSE
 ..$ : logi FALSE
 ..$ : logi FALSE

Comment: I probably needed "quotes" ... <code>list("unittest.1"=unittest.1, "unittest.2"=unittest.2, "bptest"=bptest, "viftest"=viftest, "pdwtest"=pdwtest, "pbgtest"=pbgtest, "pooled.reg"=pooled.reg, "pooled.sum"=pooled.sum, "pooled.xsd"=pooled.xsd, "pooled.coef"=pooled.coef, "fixed.reg"=fixed.reg, ..., "random.reg"=random.reg, ..., "hausmantest"=hausmantest);</code>

Comment: Still FALSE!  What's going on?

Comment: Figured it out, one of my function calls, across all 12 models was throwing an error which apparently was causing everything to return FALSE.

Comment: Works as expected thanks!  ... > str(modeldata[[4]][[3]]$hausmantest);
List of 6
$ statistic  : num [1, 1] 0.531
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "chisq"
$ p.value    : num [1, 1] 1
$ parameter  : Named int 16
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
$ method     : chr "Hausman Test"
$ data.name  : chr "mModel"
$ alternative: chr "one model is inconsistent"
- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"